# FlowException vs CordaRuntimeException

Tags: corda

When writing flow what is recommended when we have to throw exceptions? Many example shows throwing IllegalArgumentException which is a runtime exception. The 'Call' method signature for the flow shows that it throws FlowException and its a checked exception. When we are communicating over RPCClient in our rest layer we get following behavior when the exception is thrown

1. When a Checked Exception like FlowException, On RPCClient side it is thrown as UndeclaredThrowableException and the actual exception is found under undeclaredThrowable property of UndeclaredThrowableException
2. When any of the runtime exception is thrown we do get actual exception.

On rest layer side we do want exception to be recognizable so that we can provide appropriate JSON response to the UI layer. After doing some digging into Corda core we also found that there is also CordaRuntimeException class which is unchecked exception and it may be better to throw this exception instead of throwing generic IllegalArgumentException. But also at the same time FlowException needs to be thrown as needed. So my question is in what situation we need to throw FlowException vs unchecked runtime exception?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a party is running a flow instance `flowA`:

- If `flowA` throws a `FlowException`, the flow ends and the exception is propagated to every other node with an active flow session with `flowA`
- If `flowA` throws any other type of exception, the flow ends and every other node with an active flow session with `flowA` receives a generic `UnexpectedFlowEndException`

Thus `FlowException` should only be used when you want to notify counterparty nodes of the reason the flow failed (e.g. "We aren't willing to exchange USD to EUR at this rate."). Otherwise, another exception type should be thrown (e.g. because the node encountered an internal database error).